# lua io writing to specific postion

Tags: file-io, lua

if I have

foo.txt:

```
cows    = 3
sheep   = 2
chicken = 14
dogs    = 1
```

how do I write a lua script that can change the numbers or the animals or add elements to the list, I looked at the lua documentation on io (http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.8) and yet I still don't know how to do this without doing something stupid like having it rewrite the entire line each time it edits it.

Comment: I have an example of a saver/loader script using the io library. If you want you can look it over: http://hawwashsoft.proboards.com/thread/209/datasaver-module-persistently-save-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a matter of basic file IO operations (that is, not restricted to Lua), you cannot insert things into the middle of a file that already exists. You can *overwrite* data. You can append data. But you cannot insert data, such that previous data gets pushed farther down in the file.

Generally speaking, the way you deal with this is by keeping the file in memory, then writing the entire thing whenever the user says to save the data. While it's in memory, it's just a string. So you *can* do things like insert characters and so forth.

You can manufacture an insertion operation by reading all of the rest of the data in, going back to where you started to read from, write the new stuff, and then write the rest of the data you just read. But people generally don't do that unless it's absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_or_update_data_in_file(key, new_value, filespec)
  local file = assert(io.open(filespec))
  local content = file:read'*a'
  file:close()
  content, cnt = content:gsub(
    '(%f[%C]%s*'..key..'%s*=[ \t]*)[^\r\n]*',
    '%1'..new_value, 1)
  if cnt == 0 then
    content = key..' = '..new_value..'\n'..content
  end
  file = assert(io.open(filespec, 'w'))
  file:write(content)
  file:close()
end

add_or_update_data_in_file('chicken', 13.5, 'foo.txt')
```